# how can I save UPS and UPS_XML shipping rates xml request & response?

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, ups

How can I save UPS and UPS_XML shipping rates xml request & response ?

Note: save as xml format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the methods `_getCgiQuotes` (for UPS) and `_getXmlQuotes` (for UPS_XML) in the class `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups`
Those are the responsible for sending the request and handling the response to/from the API.

For example in `_getXmlQuotes` there is this line:

```
$xmlResponse = $this->_getCachedQuotes($xmlRequest);
```

before that you can log the `$xmlRequest` as you want. In a file or in the db or any other idea you have.

Also after the line `$debugData['result'] = $xmlResponse;` you can log `$xmlResponse`.
But the shipping carriers in general already have a method available called `_debug`. You can use that to log everything. Usually that method receives as parameter an array like this:

```
array('request'=>..., 'reponse'=>...);
```

You can override the UPS class and change that method to log everything you need, where you need it.

Comment: thank you for posting answer, when magento url goes to `checkout/cart/index` `collectrates()` method is calling. Can you tell me the scenario of `collectRates()`. I mean where it's calling from `checkout/cart/index` action. I searched that but i'm not getting any where. Can you tell me?

Comment: you can just enable the debug mode for that particular shipping method and there will be a shipping_{{method_name}}.log generated with request and response in it

Comment: note that the method `_getCachedQuotes()` only cache the rates for the current session: it stores them in the carrier object not in magento cache ...